# Why this code is not working as per intended

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Why `x_temp` is not updating the value, where as the commented line `x &= ~(1 << i);` is working perfectly.
Where it is going wrong?

```
int x = 0x4567;
int x_temp = 0x0;// = 0xF0FF;
int y = 0x0200;
int i;
for(i = 8; i < 12; i++)
{//clean clear
    x_temp = x & ~(1 << i);
    //x &= ~(1 << i); //This line works perfectly.
}
printf("x_temp = %x....\n", x_temp);//Still it retains the value 0x4567.
printf("x = %x....\n", x);
y = x|y; //y = x_temp|y;
printf("y = %x\n", y);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the last iteration of your loop, `i` is 11, but the 11th bit of `x` is already 0, so the result is 0x4567. I don't know why you expect something else. In the case of `x &= ~(1 << i)`, you clear a bit in the *previous* value of `x`, whereas with `x_temp` you keep assigning a fresh value to `x_temp` ... one case is cumulative, the other is not.

Consider a trace of the two loops:

> ```
> for `x &= ~(1 << i)`, you have
> x is 0x4567 originally
> x is 0x4467 after clearing 1<<8
> x is 0x4467 after clearing 1<<9
> x is 0x4067 after clearing 1<<10
> x is 0x4067 after clearing 1<<11
> ```
>
> but
>
> ```
> for `x_temp = x & ~(1 << i)`, you have
> x is 0x4567 (originally and forever)
> x_temp is 0x4467 after clearing 1<<8 from x (which hasn't changed)
> x_temp is 0x4567 after clearing 1<<9 from x (which hasn't changed)
> x_temp is 0x4167 after clearing 1<<10 from x (which hasn't changed)
> x_temp is 0x4567, after clearing 1<<11 from x (which hasn't changed)
> ```

Maybe this is clearer:
Suppose x = 5; then a loop that sets x += 1 will yield values of 6,7,8,9,10, ...
but a loop that sets x_temp = x + 1 will yield values of 6,6,6,6,6,...

Comment: When I am doing `x &= ~(1 << 11); ` the x value changes from `0x4567` to `0x4067`. But the same does not happen with `x_temp = x & ~(1 << 11);`

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak Yes, because in one case you change `x` and in the other case you don't. So when you clear the next bit in `x`, in one case you're using the modified value of `x` and in the other case you're using the original value.

Comment: Yes Yes, Now I got it. Ya my doubt got claered... Really good explanation, You guys are amazing..

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's because you're discarding the old values of `x_temp`?

```
for(i = 8; i < 12; i++)
{
    x_temp = x & ~(1 << i);
}
```

is the same as

```
x_temp = x & ~(1 << 11);
```

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak Because you keep changing x, so the changes are cumulative. You need to think this through a bit more, because it really is obvious to Zeta and me, and probably many others.

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak: `x &= v` is the same as `x = x & v`. The value of `x` changes in each iteration. However, `x_temp` isn't on the right side of the assignment, so its value is irrelevant to the result.

Comment: @Zeta: If i understood corretly, you mean to say;
if, `x += 5;`//int x = 1
then `x = 6` //Output
same above code if
`y = x + 5;` then value of `y = 5` `not` `6`. Is it?

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak: No. If `x == 1`, what's the value of the expression `x + 5`? Well, it's `1 + 5`, and `y` will be `6`.

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Compound_assignment_operators. It is very important to understand that the left hand side of the compound operator (**x** += y) will change it's value, while the left argument of an arithmetic expression (x_temp = **x** + y) won't.

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak Take a look at my answer using `+=` ... it may help you think about this.